# Return data from array into a table

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have an array that looks like this and I am trying to take three of the values and put them into a defined table.

```js
{
  "GlobalStatistics": [{
    "TotalCallsQueued": 9,
    "TotalCallsTransferred": 9,
    "TotalCallsAbandoned": 0,
    "MinQueueWaitingTime": 5,
    "MaxQueueWaitingTime": 56,
    "AvgQueueWaitingTime": 15,
    "MinTalkingTime": 8,
    "MaxTalkingTime": 913,
    "AvgTalkingTime": 240,
    "ServiceLevel": 100.0,
    "TotalVoicemails": 0,
    "TotalCallsReceived": 23,
    "AnswerRate": 100.0,
    "AbandonRate": 0.0,
    "CallbacksRegistered": 0,
    "CallbacksAnswered": 0,
    "CallbacksNotAnswered": 0,
    "CallbacksWaiting": 0
  }]
}
```

I am trying to take 3 of the values from that array and put them into a table but the value always shows as null.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  type: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'token': 'bearer TOKEN',
  },
  success: function(Global) {
    tableData.push({
      "TotalCallsQueued": Global.GlobalStatistics.TotalCallsQueued,
      "TotalCallsAbandoned": Global.GlobalStatistics.TotalCallsAbandoned,
      "AvgQueueWaitingTime": Global.GlobalStatistics.AvgQueueWaitingTime
    })
    table.appendRows(tableData);
  }
})

doneCallback();
```

Comment: Have you debugged this? What is `table` a reference to? Is `tableData` defined as an array in scope of the AJAX call? Does the AJAX call work?

Comment: What does console show inside success function when you do a `console.log(Global)` ?

Comment: Also, if you're expecting `doneCallback()` to happen *after* the AJAX request completes it needs to be placed inside the `success` handler function

Comment: But anyway, you are forgetting to access the array index, like this: `Global.GlobalStatistics[0].TotalCallsQueued`

Comment: console.log give me:
```
{GlobalStatistics: Array(1)}
GlobalStatistics: Array(1)
0:
TotalCallsQueued: 36
TotalCallsTransferred: 36
TotalCallsAbandoned: 0
MinQueueWaitingTime: 2
MaxQueueWaitingTime: 205
AvgQueueWaitingTime: 27
MinTalkingTime: 7
MaxTalkingTime: 1218
AvgTalkingTime: 276
ServiceLevel: 94.44444
TotalVoicemails: 0
TotalCallsReceived: 51
AnswerRate: 100
AbandonRate: 0
CallbacksRegistered: 0
CallbacksAnswered: 0
CallbacksNotAnswered: 0
CallbacksWaiting: 0
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: @CalvinNunes thanks man, that worked
`tableData.push({    
     "TotalCallsQueued": Global.GlobalStatistics[0].TotalCallsQueued,
     "TotalCallsAbandoned": Global.GlobalStatistics[0].TotalCallsAbandoned,
     "AvgQueueWaitingTime": Global.GlobalStatistics[0].AvgQueueWaitingTime
                }) `

Comment: Nice, glad to help, but a tipo for future questions: Don't add code or JSONs in comments, edit your question to add those relevant informations. Also, if you fixed your problem, you can answer it by yourself or delete it since nobody posted an answer